# reszing div width size with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a about 200 px width size div on the right side of the website.

It is like facebook chat box that provide recent timeline.

Here is the code that I am using to resize html div

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#right_timeline_div").css("width", $(window).width() - 1200);
});
$(window).resize(function()
{
    $("#right_timeline_div").css("width", $(window).width() - 1200);
});
```

My code only shrink certain size of div.

I would like to change the div width size when the browser gets smaller size.

Let's say if the browser is 1200px wide, then I wanna decrease the right sidebar size with jquery.

I tried a lot of methods from here but it didn't work.

Thank you for reading my question, I hope this help other viewers who have same problem like me.

Comment: you are changing the height in your code not width. must be a typo

Comment: maybe you should try `$(window).height()` to adjust the div's height to the windows height instead of the window's width.... `$("#right_timeline_div").css("height", $(window).height() - 50);`

Comment: Works fine in Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/ZwYTK/

Comment: you should look into media queries with CSS, it's a much better solution than jQuery and allows you to separate the styles from the scripting. Here's a simple example http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/8yGv4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `px` as in

```
var newSize = $(window).width() - 1200;
$("#right_timeline_div").css("width", newSize + 'px');
```

or:

```
$("#right_timeline_div").width(newSize);
```

So...

```
$(document).ready(function(){Resize_right_timeline();});
$(window).resize(function(){Resize_right_timeline();});

functiuon Resize_right_timeline(){
    var newSize = $(window).width() - 1200;
    $("#right_timeline_div").css("width", newSize + 'px');
    //                        Add This---------------^

    //OR:
   //$("#right_timeline_div").width(newSize);
}
```